# How to convert a list of list to a string in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, file-read

I have a list which I am reading from a text file 'arrowhead.txt' and it is string. I want to read the string and write it again to another text document in python.
I know I could have just copied the text from input file to destination file, but I need to use python for that.
Any help? 
Input file :

```
arrowhead
BEGIN
28,85
110,80
118,80
127,80
135,80
141,80
147,80
152,80
156,80
160,80
162,80
164,80
165,80
165,80
END
BEGIN
139,38
183,81
186,85
188,86
189,88
190,90
191,92
183,93
180,95
177,96
174,97
170,100
166,102
162,105
157,107
151,110
145,113
140,116
135,118
130,121
126,125
122,125
119,127
117,130
115,130
113,130
112,132
112,132
END
```

Output file should be in the same format. Need help!

```
with open('arrowhead.txt', 'r') as f: 
    arwhead = f.readline() 
    splited_line = ([line.rstrip().split(',') for line in f]) 
    s1 = ','.join(map(str, splited_line))
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used to read the data out of the first file?

Comment: with open('arrowhead.txt', 'r') as f:
    arwhead = f.readline()
    splited_line = ([line.rstrip().split(',') for line in f])
    s1 = ','.join(map(str, splited_line))   I am confused to what to do after this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much easier to use Pandas for this task and will create an identical copy of your text in a file name 'test_copy.csv'. Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df.to_csv('test_copy.csv', index=False)
```

Note: if you didn't install pandas you can install it using pip install pandas

Answer (score 1):

This should copy the data from `arrowhead.txt` to `output.txt`. Test this and see if it works for what you are trying to do.

```
with open('arrowhead.txt', 'r') as read_file:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        for row in read_file:
            out_file.write(row)
```